# I am unable to reach my mongodb container running on static ip

Tags: docker

I am running my MongoDB container on a static ip i.e 1.1.2.2.
I am not able to reach it through `curl`.

The only response I get is

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 1.1.2.2:xxxx; No route to host
```

or

```
tcp: connection reset by peer.
```

My docker compose is as follows:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo_hmm
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "49002:27017"
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.2.2
networks:
  static-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 1.1.2.0/24
```

and my curl command is curl localhost:49002

The output I get is  curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You probably need to specify the protocol, e.g. `tcp://1.1.2.2:xxxx`

Comment: There could be many reasons. What is your platform?

Comment: @Charlie The platform is a centos Virtual machine maintained by my infrastructure team which is behind corporate proxy.

Comment: Post your cURL too